# Proving DFT equation

Tags: dft, digital-communications, proof

How can I prove the equation $(3)$? I can't understand why there is a $2/N$ in $(3)$. Why he just get the second term in DFT?

> Consider a sinusoidal input signal of frequency $\omega$ given by
>
> $$
> x(t) = \sqrt 2 X \sin\left(\omega t + \phi\right)\tag{1}
> $$
>
> This signal is conventionally represented by a phasor (a complex number) $\bar X$
>
> $$
> \bar X = Xe^{j\phi}=X\cos\phi+jX\sin\phi\tag{2}
> $$
>
> Assuming that $x(t)$ is sampled $N$ times per cycle of the $60\textrm{ Hz}$ waveform to produce the sampled set $\left\{x_k\right\}$
>
> $$
> x_k = \sqrt 2 X\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{N}k + \phi\right)\tag{3}
> $$
>
> The Discrete Fourier Transform of $\left\{x_k\right\}$ contains a fundamental frequency component given by
>
> $$
> \color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{\bar X_1= \frac 2N \sum_{k=0}^N x_k e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k}}}}\tag{4}\\
> $$

Comment: where did this text come from??  1980 or before?  IBM Selectric Typewriters with exchangeable balls?

Comment: and, in my Electrical Engineering training and experience, Eqs (1) and (2) are incompatible.  if $$ x(t) = \sqrt{2} X \cos(\omega t + \phi) $$ (note that it's "$\cos()$", not "$\sin()$") **then** the phasor is $$ \bar{X} = X \ e^{j \phi} = X \cos(\phi) + j X \sin(\phi) $$ and $X \ge 0$ is the r.m.s. magnitude of the sinusoid.

Comment: to answer your question (once the premises are corrected), you first express what $\omega$ is (given that it's a "60 Hz waveform"). then compute what the sampling instances are (values of $t$) given that one cycle of your 60 Hz waveform is sampled with $N$ samples.  since this is one cycle going into the DFT, the complex amplitude of the fundamental is in $X_1$ and $X_{N-1}$ of the DFT output (using the crappy subscript notation from pre-1980).  and the "2" does not belong.

Comment: In that time there wasnt a clear phasor representation.

Comment: I think there may be a way to get this 2 on equation (4), there is a lot of material using this. Like this one: http://www.nptel.ac.in/courses/108101039/download/Lecture-35.pdf

Comment: I find the solution of $$ \dfrac{2}{N} \sum_{k=0}^N x_k e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k}$$. This is the firt term in discrete Fourier series $a_1$. Sorry for my cloudy question. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @RorschachOsterman : I've deleted your answer because I thought it was meant to be a comment.  Re-reading it, I'm not so sure. Let me know and I can reinstate it.  If you can edit it for clarity, that'd be good.

Comment: i suspected as much, but $$ \bar{X_1} = \frac{2}{N} \sum_{k=0}^N x_k e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k}$$ is (twice) the fourier coefficient to the first harmonic term of the **complex** fourier series.  it has both real and imaginary parts.  it is **not** the coefficient to either the $\cos()$ or $\sin()$ terms.